# PowerShell - Match multiple string entries in a CSV file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to `-match` more than one string in a CSV file. Sample CSV below:

```
Hostname,IpAddress,Domain
x200apple300,1.2.3.4,contoso.local
x200banana300,1.2.3.5,contoso.local
x200orange300,1.2.3.6,contoso.local
x200kiwi300,1.2.3.7,contoso.local
```

Sample code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Files\csvExample.csv"
$csv | Where-Object {$_.Hostname -match "kiwi"}
# All OK. Now match multiple hostnames.

$csv | Where-Object {$_.Hostname -match "kiwi", "orange"}
# Not working.

$csv | Where-Object {$_.Hostname -contains "apple", "banana"}
# Not working
```

How can I match multiple hostnames in this example? What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match takes a regex expression, so you can use an `or` operator to filter on multiple values.

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Files\csvExample.csv"
$csv | Where-Object {$_.Hostname -match "kiwi|orange|banana"}
```

Comment: Or use the -or operator

Answer (score 3):

The `-match` operator expects a regex on the right hand side. I'm not sure what `$Value -match $A, $B` means; it's not documented that I can see and it seems to always return false from my input.

`$_.Hostname -contains "apple", "banana"` is backwards. You want either `{$_.Hostname -in "apple", "banana"}` or `{"apple", "banana" -contains $_.Hostname}`.

Comment: `$Value -match $A, $B` _stringifies_ the RHS array, so it is effectively the same as `$Value -match "$A $B"`, which is rarely useful; e.g., `'fo o' -match 'o', 'o'` is `$true`.